# How to swap 2 elements in Vector of Vector

Tags: clojure

How do I extend this:
[What is the idiomatic way to swap two elements in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979538/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-swap-two-elements-in-a-vector)

to essentially a 2D array?

```
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] --> [[1 2 5] [4 3 6] [7 8 9]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [get-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) and [assoc-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in):

```
(defn swap-in [vv p1 p2]
  (let [v1 (get-in vv p1)
        v2 (get-in vv p2)
    (-> vv 
        (assoc-in p1 v2)
        (assoc-in p2 v1))))
```

So now:

```
(def my-vec [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
(swap-in my-vec [0 2] [1 1])
=> [[1 2 5] [4 3 6] [7 8 9]]
```

This will work with vectors nested to any "depth", so long as the specified positions in my-vec actually exist.